# The size of dynamic response body is over the limit

Tags: php, apache, download, litespeed, force-download

I'm trying to create temporary download link.

The main problem is that the download always stop when file reach 1Go.
When i use `tail` on the downloaded file I get this error :

`The size of dynamic response body is over the limit, response is truncated by web server. The limit is set by the 'Max Dynamic Response Body Size' in tuning section  of server configuration.`

I'm using apache and php 7.0

PHP `memory_limit` is already set to `20G`

I can't find anything about this php "Max Dynamic Response Body Size" setting in php.ini.

Any idea ?

**Update:**

I updated the "Max Dynamic Response Body Size" to 128M in the lightSpeed main panel, but the result is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more search i found that the server wasn't using Apache but LiteSpeed,
To correct this error you must change the `Max Dynamic Response Body Size` configuration with web admin wich default port is `:7080`