# Mysql ERROR 1064 while importing database via SSH

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, webmin, cyber-panel

I just take a backup from my webmin server and want to restore it on cyberpanel since the database is large I was restoring it via command line. but I am getting an error

```
ERROR 1064
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 76929: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ‘

The dynamic response body size is over the limit, the response will be tru…’ at line 129
```

Comment: I got you, check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386110/the-size-of-dynamic-response-body-is-over-the-limit

Comment: You need to change some MySQL settings (Max Dynamic Response Body Size ) to allow such a big import (TLDR)